# Get result using two queries

Tags: sql, view

I have two tables: `tbl_mostvisitedposts` which has fields (id, classifiedid, city, views), `tbl_classifieds` which has fields (classifiedid, city, classifiedname).

I want to retrieve classified name which have the most visited views. I did following but it says:

> 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Please help me.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_classifieds WHERE classifiedid=(SELECT id FROM tbl_mostvisitedposts WHERE city='mumbai') LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_classifieds WHERE classifiedid IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM tbl_mostvisitedposts WHERE city='mumbai') LIMIT 5
```

or use a join

```
SELECT c.* FROM tbl_classifieds c JOIN tbl_mostvisitedposts mst ON (c.classifiedid=mst.id)
WHERE mst.city='mumbai' LIMIT 5
```